# How to terminate worker thread properly in an injected DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, dll

I'm injecting a DLL into some process, the DLL has a worker thread that is running a message loop.

I'd like to quit the thread properly i.e. post a quit message (PostThreadMessage) and wait for it (WaitForSingleObject).

Where can i wait for this thread to close? I can't do it on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH because by then all of the threads are closed or terminated and I don't know when the process is about to close.

My only thought was, Is there a way to intercept the main thread message loop and look for the WM_CLOSE\DESTROY msgs?

I'd love to hear any other ideas\solutions.

Edit:
**Tried to hook the main thread using SetWindowsHookEx with WH_CALLWNDPROC but it didn't worked quite well, I managed to hook and receive the thread's messages. However, I didn't received WM_QUIT message only WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY and they are all were associated with windows.**

Thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to perform some action on "About-To-Close" you need to hook the main thread using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WH_CALLWNDPROC and look for WM_CLOSE and take action/signal the thread to close.

Comment: Thanks, trying that, sounds like exactly what I've been looking for :)

Comment: It didn't worked quite well, I manage to hook and receive the thread's messages. However, I don't receive WM_QUIT message only WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY and they are all associated with windows.

Comment: To be aware of WM_QUIT, WH_CALLWNDPROC is the wrong kind of hook to use (as a window procedure is not going to be called with WM_QUIT). You need to use a WH_GETMESSAGE hook to be aware of WM_QUIT.

Comment: @Logan - Used WH_GETMESSAGE, but still not all processes returned WM_QUIT

Comment: Use spy++ to see if the window uses WM_CLOSE. WM_CLOSE is what you are looking for not WM_QUIT.

Comment: Note that this depends entirely on the design of the program you're injecting into.  The obvious counter-example is that a program with multiple windows might receive a WM_CLOSE even though it is not about to exit.  There is no universal solution.

Answer (score 4):

The process has no clue that the thread exists, it is not going to care whether it exits nicely.  In fact, it will terminate it if the program was written in, say, C, its runtime library calls TerminateProcess when its main() method exits.  Harikiri style.

If you *externally* care about the thread, say in a program that you wrote that is monitoring the thread, then you need to leave a breadcrumb when it exits.  Either by communicating that to your program with whatever process interop mechanism you use, like a named pipe.  Or by setting a named event.  Do make sure you deal with the harikiri scenario, you'll want to also check if the process handle gets signaled to indicate that it terminated.

Comment: Thanks but i need to tale care of it internally, I'll try cprogrammer's solution.